# jQuery Droppable getting id of item above

Tags: jquery, droppable

I am looking for help please on getting the `id` in the dropped container using jQuery draggable and droppable. I just have two UL with listitems and I drag from list 1 to list 2. I need to get the `id` of the item above the dropped item in list 2.

It is NOT getting `$(this).attr("id")` as both lists are flagged as Sortable as per the basic jQuery example. The reason I want to do this is that each list item has an order, when I drop an item, I want to set the order between the one above it and the one below such that when reloaded from a database it displays in the order that the item was dropped into. Therefore if I get the item above it I will be able to get the order to add to.

Have not included code as it is the same as the standard jQuery sample code of dragging from one list to another.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code at the drop point

```
 $("#sortable1").sortable({
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
              var itemId = ui.item.attr('id');
              var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
              alert(droppableId);

              //--Get DOM value
              $.getJSON('/Dom/_ElementDetail/' + itemId, function (data) {
                  //--Save to new table
              var name = data[0].Name;
              var code = data[0].DomDetail;
              var matterId = localStorage['MatterId'];
              var stepId = localStorage['StepId'];
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: '/DOM/AddElementMaster',
                  data: { name: name, code: code, matterId: matterId, stepId: stepId }
              });

        });
      }

    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: show us your code or share it on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: can you provide html markup. `$(this)` in sortable therms should be element with selector `#sortable1` which element you want it to be ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)

As I understand you setted up an event `drop` or `over` like this:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function() {
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

but as told in docs you should use

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log(ui.draggable.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

same for `over` event

---

As you use sortable the info about drag operation can be got by the following:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var sender_id = ui.sender.attr('id'),
            receiver_id = $(this).attr('id'),
            item_id = ui.item.attr('id'),
            above_id = ui.item.prev().attr('id'),
            below_id = ui.item.next().attr('id');

        console.log("The item '" + item_id 
                    + "' was dragged from " + sender_id 
                    + "to '" + receiver_id 
                    + "'" + (above_id ? " below of '" + above_id + "', " : "") 
                    + (below_id ? " above of '" + below_id + "'" : "")
                   );
    },
    connectWith: ".sortable"
});​
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CfkXN/)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to tell me? I have added the code for the droppable. The value of this that gets logged is the total user list. I am using sortable rather than droppable as I want to be able to sort that list also

Comment: Thanks, what you are suggesting does not appear to work. The sender_id and receiver_id is giving the value of the class of the UL, not an ID or the LI. I assume it is because the draggable and droppable is the ID of the UL, not LI. However, if I change to the LI, then drag attampts to drag the whole UL, not just the LI. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @user1724268 item_id is id of the `li` , which id you want else  ?

Comment: if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CfkXN/3/) is not enough then your task most probably about nothing, like 'i want square circle looking like star'

Comment: ecicto, I am not sure why the smart aleck comment, I hope it makes you feel better! The reason I hadn't responded as I am probably on the other side of the earth than you, hence time differences.

Comment: I am looking for the item_Id of the receiving list? I do not understand how you think your answer provides that? Item_Id is from the draggable, sender_id and receiver_id are of the UL not LI

Comment: give a sample, what `li` you want ?

Comment: Thanks Eicto! No I hadn't seen the fiddle. The fiddle IS doing what I want, not sure why my code isn't but I am sure I will not find it. Thankyou VERY much for your effort.